# moving the function from preferenceFragment to the second fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, fragment, data-transfer

Well, I have a question, how to pass a function or its value to the second fragment? I am using the MVVM structure? I am exactly making an application in which in settingsFragment you select the csv file you want to read and send the result to the fragment with the graph and draws the graph for you. I've already done selecting the csv file but don't know how to read it and transfer the data from the file to the second fragment? Take a look at my code, if there is anything incomprehensible in the question or code, ask

SettingsFragment

```
class SettingsFragment : PreferenceFragmentCompat() {
    private val SETTINGS_DEBUG = "PROFILE_DEBUG"

    private var resolver = requireActivity().contentResolver

    override fun onCreatePreferences(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, rootKey: String?) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.root_preferences, rootKey)


    val myPref: Preference? = findPreference("load_csv_file") as Preference?
        myPref?.onPreferenceClickListener = Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener {
            try {
                val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
                intent.type = "text/*"
                startActivity(intent)
            }catch (exc: Exception) {
                Log.d(SETTINGS_DEBUG, exc.message.toString())
            }
            true
        }

         fun readCSV(uri: Uri?): List<String> {
            if (uri != null) {
                val csvFile = resolver.openInputStream(uri)
                val isr = InputStreamReader(csvFile)
                return BufferedReader(isr).readLines()
            }
            return Collections.emptyList()
        }

    }

}
```

ChartFragment

```
class ChartFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentChartBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    private var resolver = requireActivity().contentResolver
    private val lineChartVm by viewModels<ChartViewModel>()

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentChartBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

            val getContent = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.GetContent()) { uri: Uri? ->
                val lines = readCSV(uri)
                val newEntries = lines.map { line -> toEntry(line) }.groupingBy { entry -> entry.x }
                    .reduce { _, accumulator, element -> if (accumulator.y > element.y) accumulator else element }.values
                val lineChart = binding.lineChart
                val vl = LineDataSet(newEntries.toList().take(4000), "cost")
                vl.setDrawValues(false)
                vl.setDrawFilled(true)
                vl.lineWidth = 1.5f
                vl.fillColor = R.color.gray
                vl.fillAlpha = R.color.red
                vl.setDrawCircles(false)
                lineChart.data = LineData(vl)
                lineChart.notifyDataSetChanged()
                lineChart.animateX(1800, Easing.EaseInExpo)
                lineChart.description.isEnabled = false
                lineChart.isHighlightPerDragEnabled = false
                lineChart.isScaleYEnabled = false
                lineChart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
            }
            

        val markerView = CustomMarker(activity?.applicationContext, R.layout.marker_view)
        binding.lineChart.marker = markerView


        return binding.root
    }
    private fun toEntry(line: String): Entry {
        val split = line.split(";")
        val time = split[1]
        // idx 01234 012345 l:5 lub 6
        // val 84504 165959
        // 0, 3 - 845
        val secondsStartIdx = time.length - 2
        val minutesStartIdx = time.length - 4
        val hoursStartIdx = (time.length - 6).coerceAtLeast(0)

        val hour = time.substring(hoursStartIdx, hoursStartIdx + time.length - 4)
        val minutest = time.substring(minutesStartIdx, minutesStartIdx + 2)
        val seconds = time.substring(secondsStartIdx, secondsStartIdx + 2)

        val newTime =
            hour.toFloat() * 10000 + (minutest.toFloat() * 100 / 60).toInt() * 100 + (seconds.toFloat() * 100 / 60).toInt()
        return Entry(newTime, split[2].toFloat())
    }



    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

Comment: With MVVM you’d probably send the result to a ViewModel though some ViewModel function that passes those results to a LiveData or SharedFlow that the fist fragment is observing.

Comment: @Tenfour04 and you would send a link or show what this function looks like

Comment: @Tenfour04 Are you help me?

Comment: @Tenfour04 look at my code and tell me what myCsvResault is

Comment: This line will crash: `private var resolver = requireActivity().contentResolver` because you can't call `requireActivity()` at Fragment class initialization time. Wrap it in `lazy` like this: `private val resolver by lazy { requireContext().contentResolver }`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 and how can I transfer this data from readCSV to chartFragment (see edit)

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense to me. How does the SettingsFragment have anything to do with the ChartFragment? It looks like you directly open an Activity to get the URI you need from the ChartFragment.

Comment: @Tenfour04 or how should I do it

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have any more time to devote to this problem. You keep changing what you're asking and the details of what your problem actually is, and there isn't enough information to understand what you are trying to do exactly. When I ask for clarification, you don't provide it.

Comment: I provide, whad do you mean?

Comment: I asked the purpose of the SettingsFragment and how it is related to the problem but you didn’t answer. Regardless, I don’t have this much time to devote to the problem, sorry. There are many articles and tutorials about how to structure and app. Since your question is open ended you can probably get better help on an Android developer message board.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a lot of detail in the question, so I can only give a very general example and use made up class names and function arguments. This should give you an idea of the basic pattern to use.

Use a shared ViewModel in both Fragments. That means it is scoped to the Activity instead of the Fragment lifecycle. You can do this by using the `activityViewModels()` property delegate. In both Fragments, it would look like this:

```
val myViewModel: MyViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

In MVVM, your ViewModel class should be responsible for finding the file and reading it (or delegating to some other class to do so), so your `readCSV` function should be moved there. And it can parse the results into however you need them. File reading needs to be done on a background thread, and this is most easily done using coroutines started from `viewModelScope`. Results can be published to a LiveData.

```
class MyViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val mutableCsvResultLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
    val csvResultLiveData: LiveData<List<String>> get() = mutableCsvResultLiveData 

    fun readCSV(uri: Uri?, resolver: ContentResolver) {
        uri ?: return // I would just make uri non-nullable so you don't need this
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            try {
                val csvFileInputStream = resolver.openInputStream(uri)
                check(csvFileInputStream != null) { "ContentResolver provider crashed" }
                val isr = InputStreamReader(csvFileInputStream)
                val result = BufferedReader(isr).readLines()
                mutableCsvResultLiveData.postValue(result)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("readCSV", "Failed to read file", e)
                return@launch
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then one fragment can initiate the file operation and parsing by calling `myViewModel.readCSV()`. The other fragment can observe the LiveData to react to the data when it arrives:

```
myViewModel.csvResultLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { csvLines -> 
    // do something with csvLines, a List<String>
}
```

Comment: What is myCsvResault?

Comment: That represents whatever you need it to be. You said you needed to pull some data out of the file.

Comment: I meant that I have done downloading the csv file and reading data from it but I do not know how to send the result to another fragment

Comment: My answer explains exactly how to do that with MVVM.

Comment: look at my code and tell me what myCsvResault is

Comment: It would be `List<String>`. I updated my answer to use your code and function name. You should move the function into your ViewModel.

Comment: and how can I transfer this data from readCSV to chartFragment (see edit)